# Как обработать window.onerror в iframe?

Tags: javascript

Создаю айфрейм так:

```
var айфрейм = document.createElement('iframe')
айфрейм.id = 'окно_запуска'    
айфрейм.srcdoc = 'тут html-документ...'
document.body.appendChild(айфрейм)
```

Внутри 'html-документа' есть обработчик ошибок window.onerror, который через alert() выводит сообщение об ошибке:

```
window.onerror = function(
    сообщение_ошибки, 
    адрес_ошибки, 
    номер_строки_ошибки
   )
{
   alert(
         'ERROR: ' + сообщение_ошибки 
         + ' URL: ' + адрес_ошибки 
         + ' LINE: ' + номер_строки_ошибки
   );
}
```

На десктопе работает нормально.

Внутри `phonegap`-приложения тоже.
Но в мобильных браузерах (`ios`) в сообщении об ошибке пустые поля **адрес_ошибки** и **номер_строки_ошибки**.
То есть ошибка отлавливается но неизвестно где она произошла,
и в **сообщение_ошибки** нет подробностей об ошибке, просто *ошибка жс*.

Как это можно сделать?
Или это невозможно?